# How can I extend a class when using import from different files?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, import

I am trying to make a game which has some subclasses, which are all imported from a single file. It works fine if I try to make the map class global, but when i try to make it a subclass by extending the engine, it says engine isn't defined yet. How do I overcome this?

html:

```
<script type="module">
    import './game.js';
</script>
```

game.js:

```
import Engine from './engine.js';
var game = new Engine();
```

engine.js

```
import Map from './map.js';
export default class Engine { }
```

map.js

```
import Engine from './engine.js';
export default class Map extends Engine { }
```

Error:

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `Engine' before initialization

Comment: Engine's module imports map, and extends engine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue here is you import Map.js into Engine.js and Engine.js into Map.js, such that it creates a "circular dependency". It seems this is possible when you are compiling your modules with a tool like webpack, but not when you are using browser-native module imports.

An article: https://medium.com/content-uneditable/circular-dependencies-in-javascript-a-k-a-coding-is-not-a-rock-paper-scissors-game-9c2a9eccd4bc

Comment: I'm not trying to create circular dependencies, but how am I supposed to extend a class from a different file without them? without it, it just says Engine is not defined

Comment: remove the line `import Map from './map.js';` from engine.js